# roslaunch gazebo_ros symbol lookup error

Tags: ros, gazebo, wxwidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am setting up gazebo on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro. Installation is done using debs.
I have following output on lauching willowgarage world.

```
/opt/ros/hydro/share/gazebo_ros/launch$ roslaunch willowgarage_world.launch 
... logging to /home/nitin/.ros/log/0bc030d2-8882-11e3-81c2-00216a476f4e/roslaunch-nitin-laptop-13134.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://nitin-laptop:36958/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13148]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 0bc030d2-8882-11e3-81c2-00216a476f4e
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13161]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [13175]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [13180]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.gzserver: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 13175, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/willowgarage.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/nitin/.ros/log/0bc030d2-8882-11e3-81c2-00216a476f4e/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/nitin/.ros/log/0bc030d2-8882-11e3-81c2-00216a476f4e/gazebo-2*.log
............
```

If I start gzserver independently, then gazebo client GUI do popup but with empty world. No models are shown.
Any idea how this can be sorted out?

rgds
nitin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123716/roslaunch-gazebo_ros-symbol-lookup-error/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be fixed now. After I upgraded my gazebo packages, it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins-current
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-current
```

---

Originally posted by [sep300](https://answers.ros.org/users/11656/sep300/) with karma: 61 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-02-06**:
Hey @sep300 ,  I am having the same problem as the person asking the question is. I used the two commands you mentioned and found the problem still there. What I realzied was that those two commands update Gazebo not just the ros gazebo pckgs , and it updates Gazebo to 2.2.1. What version do u have?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess that'd be again this problem:

http://answers.ros.org/question/121266/undefined-symbol/#121291

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1